# Under what conditions would this modification to relativity be testable?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, lorentz-symmetry

In relativity, any two timelike-separated points can be connected by timelike paths of arbitrarily low duration (as measured by the proper time of the path). Suppose this was modified so that the shortest possible duration grew with (the square root of) the spacetime interval, but slowly, i.e. sublinearly.

Presumably, if the growth was still close to linear then this modification would be easy to falsify, whereas if it was close to constant then it would be impossible to distinguish from ordinary relativity. In what regime would it be realistically testable, either with experiments or astronomical observations? I am especially interested in the case where the rate of growth is roughly logarithmic.

Also, just to check: would this modification necessarily imply a preferred frame of reference? I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that ultra-relativistic particle speeds would have an upper limit $v<c$, with $v$ getting smaller as the distance increases? If so, then measurements of speeds of neutrinos from distant supernovae could be a useful test.

Comment: My basic understanding suggests that linear growth amounts to a constant bound on time dilation, hence constant max speed, with distance; and that growth slower than this would actually allow arbitrarily extreme time dilation (hence speeds) as distance increases. However, max speed *increasing* over large distances makes no apparent sense, so either my understanding is beyond useless or something more subtle is going on: for example, I could believe that the relationship between speed and time dilation is modified.

Comment: Robin Saunders, @PM 2Ring, can you please mention some  material that I might refer to to learn a bit more about what you have asked, cause I didn't know one could connect two such events by arbitrarily small time like paths

Comment: @Astik It's just simple time dilation. If the interval from event A to event B is timelike, you can travel from A to B at less than lightspeed. And the faster you travel, the less time will pass for you.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, Oh, so it's in reference of a different observer than the one used initially, right? Cause moving the same reference frame will take us out of context of special relativity

Comment: @Astik Yes, it's a different observer. All observers will agree on the spacetime interval between A & B, but they will disagree on the space component and the time component of that interval.

Comment: @PM2Ring Actually, from what you've just said I think there might be a misunderstanding between us. I'm not talking about different time components in different inertial frames, but different durations of the paths themselves as measured by the proper time of each path. Different reference frames will agree on these proper-time durations. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Technically you can view this proper time in terms of the timelike components of infinitesimal spacetime intervals along the path, as measured by the path. But the path as a whole does not have a single inertial frame, so its proper time can't be viewed as its timelike duration in some inertial frame.

Comment: @Robin Understood. I wanted to keep things simple to get the core principle across to Astik, which is why I was talking about a straight worldline in flat spacetime. And of course we can analyse any timelike trajectory as a sequence of small straight segments.

Comment: Ok, just thought I might have miscommunicated. Astik's confusion could have stemmed from ambiguity in my wording - e.g. when I referred to paths between the same events having different durations, what did I actually mean? The most familiar context for measuring different durations between the same events is when the observers aren't present at both events (since there's only a single inertial frame present at both!) but I'm not sure modifying these two situations is equivalent - see my reply to your comment yesterday. I guess the standard example that's directly relevant is the twin paradox.